# regex parenthese in capturing group

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have this REGEX expression I use to find word in a text through an SQL query

```
[SQL QUERY] where REGEX concat(^|’| | | |\'|>|-)','Mercure','( | | |.|,|<|-) = 1
```

That work the way I want (for some reasons, the traditional word boundaries don't do the job). I would like to add to each capturing group respectively an opening parenthesis and a closing one. But when I try :

```
(^|’| | | |\'|>|-|\()','Mercure','( | | |.|,|<|-|\))
```

Then I get an error with my PHP script, although regex101 doesn't seem to find this odd. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that ?

Comment: Please paste your PHP code.

Comment: Maybe you want `REGEX concat('[[:<:]]','Mercure','[[:>:]]')` if you need to match whole words with MySQL?

Comment: Thanks so much Wiktor : but does those word boundaries deal with cases like apostrophe ? like in the french "j'aime", aime have to be considered as a whole word. I think that is why I chose to deal with it that way back then. I would like to be wrong, though : this is way better...

Comment: Bartosz : thanks ! I will asap. But a tool like Sequel also raise an error when I am trying to do that so I suppose PHP code isn't the problem here.

Comment: Sorry... end of work day. Yep j'aime should be considered as two words, wheter the apostrophe is a straight or curved one... not sure the word boundaries are dealing with that correctly...

Comment: In PHP, a whole word is matched with `\b` - `preg_match('~\bMercure\b~', $s, $match)`

Comment: See `FULLTEXT` indexing for 'word' searches.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE col REGEXP "(^|[’ '>-])Mercure[ .,<-]"
```

I don't understand having multiple blanks.

It is not easy to look for `>` matched only by `<` -- that would probably take a long list of choices.

One way to approach the problem (if it is complex) is to do only this in MySQL:

```
WHERE col LIKE '%Mercure%'
```

then use PHP code to filter out the rows that don't match the complex boundary conditions.

Comment: Oops - There is a flaw.  `REGEXP` only works with bytes, not multi-byte characters such as `’`.  The regexp won't 'fail', but it might act funny in some situations.